# Cluster & Average linestring based on similarity

Tags: postgis, linestring, convex-hull

I am looking for a way to find the "average" linestring of a set of linestrings using postgis 3. Ideally the collection of linestrings should be clustered based on their similarity (Perhaps ST_ClusterWithin on their start- and endpoints) and then calculate one linestring to represent the cluster:
[image]

The resulting "average linestring" should ideally hold information on how many linestrings it was created from.

This is my solution so far:

```
WITH 

-- Get 500 newest paths from a specific map
Paths AS (SELECT "Path" FROM "Tracks" WHERE "MapId" = 1 ORDER BY "EndTime" DESC LIMIT 500),

-- Cluster the paths by startpoints within X distance and with minimum Y points
Clusters AS (SELECT ST_ClusterDBSCAN(ST_StartPoint("Path"), 0.0000075, 25) over () as "Cluster", "Path" FROM Paths),

-- Group each cluster as a multilinestring and drop M values
ClusteredPaths AS (SELECT "Cluster", ST_Collect(ST_Force2D("Path")) as "Paths" FROM Clusters WHERE "Cluster" IS NOT NULL GROUP BY "Cluster"),

-- For each cluster, calculate the hull containing the multilinestring and count how many paths make up the cluster
ClusterHulls AS (SELECT "Cluster", ST_NumGeometries("Paths") as "Count", ST_ConvexHull("Paths") as "Hull" FROM ClusteredPaths),
-- ERROR: ClusterHulls AS (SELECT "Cluster", ST_NumGeometries("Paths") as "Count", ST_ConcaveHull("Paths", 0.99) as "Hull" FROM ClusteredPaths),

-- For each cluster, approximate the median axis of the hull and smooth it
ClusterApprox AS (SELECT "Cluster", "Count", ST_ChaikinSmoothing(ST_ApproximateMedialAxis("Hull")) as "Path" FROM ClusterHulls)

SELECT * FROM ClusterApprox
```

It works fine with `ST_ConvexHull`, however `ST_ConcaveHull` (which is better suited for my case) breaks `ST_ApproximateMedialAxis()` with the following **Error**:

> NOTICE:  During approximate_medial_axis(A) : NOTICE:    with A:
> GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(LINESTRING(7074285800422757/562949953421312
> 7836752340625437/140737488355328,7074285814669309/562949953421312...
>
> ERROR:  GeometryCollection is invalid : LineString 6 is invalid: no
> length :
> GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(LINESTRING(7074285800422757/562949953421312
> 7836752340625437/140737488355328,7074285814669309/562949953421312
> 7836752336734937/140737488355328,3537143651774571/281474976710656...
>
> SQL state: XX000

Even when applying `ST_IsValid`, `ST_MakeValid` or even filtering out very short paths i.e. `ST_Length("Path") > x` it still breaks.

Comment: The intensity of an approach depends on the complexity of your LineStrings; the above example could be solved by clustering the line centroids, and getting the average x and y of both extreme points. Any more complexity (+2 vertices, stronger overlap patterns) and it get's a lot more difficult.

Comment: @geozelot please see my edit above - thanks!